# How do i set int value of inputfield with Content Type set to Integer in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity 2018.
I have inputfield and 2 buttons.

When i click a button the expected behaviour is for the counter inside the field to change accordingly. For example:

```
    {
        int current_value = int.Parse(this.craftOrderInput.text);
        if(current_value>0)
            this.craftOrderInput.text = (current_value - 1) + "";
    }
```

But this obviously fails because the  `(current_value - 1) + "";` is a string, but input field expects an integer. Setting an integer like so `this.craftOrder.text = (current_value - 1) ;` obviously cannot compile because text component expects a string.
I wanted to try Unity forums first but i cannot ask questions there because my style of writing reminds them of spam.

tldr; How do i set int value of inputfield with Content Type set to Integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type only affects which characters the user is allowed to type in the inputfield. Even when the content type is set to integer, changing the input field is still done by changing the text as a string. I made a little demo to test this and the following script worked for me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MakeSmaller : MonoBehaviour {
    InputField inputField;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
    }

    public void Subtract()
    {
        int orig = int.Parse(inputField.text);
        inputField.text = (orig - 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found my error. I was setting the Text component of a child object of inputField, not the Inputfield.text, but more like  inputfield.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>(). silly me